# Get .tif and .jpg image tags using PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, exif

When I use Windows Explorer to view the Properties of an image file, I see "Tags" under the Description section of the Details tab.

Is it possible to get these "Tags" using PHP?

I have looked at the documentation for [`exif_read_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) on the PHP site. However, I only see code for getting reading dimensions and comments.

Comment: Please give examples of your code, and any attempts you have made to achieve what you want

Comment: I've shortened the link to the PHP documentation. I've also clarified that the Tags property comes from Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first example on the page you linked does just that: [Example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#example-3431)

With the `IFD0` option you get all tags, so just implement it like this and use the tags you need.